# Saving photo in different genre

Tags: ios, gallery, photo

Hi I am making a gallery app that will save photo's into different genre's for example, fruits, meat and fish. However I have written the code that the user takes a square picture. However I do not know how to save it since I want it to be saved into different genre's(not in the photo library) and can be recalled by another view controller so that it can be displayed like a gallery.  I also want the user to choose which genre he wants to save.  What am I suppose to do if I want to achieve this kind of action?
This is my code below

```
- (void) initializeCamera {
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    [captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.imagePreview.bounds;
    [self.imagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    UIView *view = [self imagePreview];
    CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
    [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    CGRect bounds = [view bounds];
    [captureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:bounds];

    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
    AVCaptureDevice *frontCamera;
    AVCaptureDevice *backCamera;

    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {

        NSLog(@"Device name: %@", [device localizedName]);

        if ([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {

            if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
                NSLog(@"Device position : back");
                backCamera = device;
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Device position : front");
                frontCamera = device;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!FrontCamera) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:backCamera error:&error];
        if (!input) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
        }
        [session addInput:input];
    }

    if (FrontCamera) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontCamera error:&error];
        if (!input) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
        }
        [session addInput:input];
    }

    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

    [session startRunning];
}




- (IBAction)snapImage:(id)sender {
    if (!haveImage) {
        captureImage.image = nil; //remove old image from view
        captureImage.hidden = NO; //show the captured image view
        imagePreview.hidden = YES; //hide the live video feed
        [self capImage];
    }
    else {
        captureImage.hidden = YES;
        imagePreview.hidden = NO;
        haveImage = NO;
    }
}

- (void) capImage { //method to capture image from AVCaptureSession video feed
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections) {

        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {

            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        if (imageSampleBuffer != NULL) {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
            [self processImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
        }
    }];
}


- (void) processImage:(UIImage *)image { //process captured image, crop, resize and rotate
    haveImage = YES;

    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { //Device is ipad
        // Resize image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(768, 1022));
        [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1022)];
        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 130, 768, 768);
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);
        //or use the UIImage wherever you like

        [captureImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
        captureImage.hidden = NO;

    }else{ //Device is iphone
        // Resize image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 426));
        [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 426)];
        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 55, 320, 320);
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);

        [captureImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    }

    //adjust image orientation based on device orientation
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"landscape left image");

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(-90));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"landscape right");

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(90));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        NSLog(@"upside down");
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(180));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"upside upright");
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(0));
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will always be created in Camera Roll (iOS issue) but you can create Custom album using category described in this [tutorial](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/). I use this in my project and it works well.

But you'll have to write some method for loading photos from custom gallery or for picking the gallery.

Comment: you cannot save it in the app? I don't want it to be saved in the Camera Roll

Comment: You can create a custom album below the camera roll but it also would be saved to camera roll... But you can save thos photos in your phone without posting them inside gallery folder. You can do it anywhere using `NSFileManager`

Comment: Wait I want to bring back the question back, I have an app that has an camera button which I can take pictures, i want the user to select where the picture to save for example, fruits, vegetables, etc.  Is it possible to have multiple directory so that I can sort the pictures that I have taken and be recalled for example show the pictures for fruits or like show pictures of vegetables?

Comment: Okey I got your point of view and I will repeat myself:

Yes you can do it and you can use yours phone **Documents** directory. When you save photos there you can access them with `NSFileManager`.

I recommend reading [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: OK thanks now I want to know if I can sort the pictures in the documents directory so that I can sort the pictures into Genre's.. Sorry I am new to Objective-C..

Comment: But I don't get why you want sort pictures? I guess you would like to save taken pictures to proper folder (generes)? Youc can look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html) or you can create a `NSArray` and sort it with `NSSortDescriptor`.

Comment: I am making an app that is like a fridgerator app where the user can take a picture inside the app and then sort it to a food genre like meat and vege.  So when I go to the homescreen of the app I can select which food Genre I want to see and when I Touch the button it shows me the photo that I took.   I just want to do this task and I'm very confused...

Comment: So here is what I would do:

1. Create the Genere dirs in **Documents**;
2. When the photo is taken it shows `UIPickerView` to pick the genere;
3. It saves photo to given dir which is named as a food genere;
4. Display a list with all food gener folders (saving names to `NSArray` and displaying in `UITableView`);
5. When one genere is selected we move to detail view and show all food photos.

Sorry, but I've no time to write this and show you the complete code for your task. But feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks Im now getting a general picture of it. Sorry for many questions so it means that I can have multiple folders in the directory so that I can take the picture and then save it into the folders that I made?

Comment: **Exactly!** It's like creating folder, subfolder etc on your computer so you can enter and manage created folders.